# numpy.arctanh(x) for x >= 1 returns NaN but I want complex

Tags: python, numpy, nan, complex-numbers

When I perform the operation numpy.arctanh(x) for x >= 1, it returns nan, which is odd because when I perform the operation in Wolfram|alpha, it returns complex values, which is what I need for my application. 
Does anyone know what I can do to keep Numpy from suppressing complex values?

Comment: There should be a tick mark next to Paul's answer that'll allow you to accept it.  No need for the "Solved" edit. :-)

Comment: It's great to see these 3D models behaving properly for once. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `+0j` to your real inputs to make them complex numbers.

Numpy is following a variation of the maxim "Garbage in, Garbage out."

Float in, float out.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.sqrt(-1)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
nan
```

Complex in, complex out.

```
>>> numpy.sqrt(-1+0j)
1j
>>> numpy.arctanh(24+0j)
(0.0416908044695255-1.5707963267948966j)
```

Comment: Hmm.  That looks like the wrong branch: the imaginary part of the result should really be +1.5707...

Comment: Take the complex conjugate with [numpy.conj()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.conj.html)?

Comment: Nah, I'm just being extra fussy about branch cuts.  Kahan gave suggestions decades ago about how they should work on an IEEE 754-supporting machine, namely that the sign of the real part (in the case of atanh) should be used to determine which side of the branch cut a point lies.  It appears that NumPy doesn't follow those suggestions: `arctanh` of `complex(24, 0.0)` and of `complex(24, -0.0)` both give the same result, which is a bit disappointing.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Try +/- 0.000001j and it gives different branches.  So in python 2.7.9 `0.0j==-0.0j` is `True` but `0.0j is -0.0j` is `False`, so it is certainly possible to code the limits properly as well... although as you point out, they appear not to be....